# MYSQL Doing Relationships right

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I am stepping into the world of relationships between tables and running into a few issues.

I have 3 tables:

```
Client
 + id
 + alias

Client_Manager
 + id
 + user_id
 + client_id

Client_Facebook
 + id
 + facebook_page_id
 + client_id
```

I made my tables a one to many with the client.id to tables.client_ids in mysql Workbench and synchronised. This worked as expected but when I built the ObjectRelationshipMapper using Zend the child tables classes we're bugged.

So i redid my relationships, making the child tables have the relationship from their client id to client.id

My models built correctly.

My question really, is should I make the relationships on the parent table, the child tables or both?

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but your model looks pretty fine to me like this.

Comment: My question really is should the relationship be on the parent, the children only or made on both?